# Intersection of a 3d curve with a rectangle

Tags: python, math, intersection

I couldnt find a solution to my problem :
I have a 3D curve defined in python by 3 lists, X Y and Z.

I want to know whether this curve intersects with a certain rectangle (for instance  it's normal to the y axis) using a function looking like this :

```
def curve_intersects(X,Y,Z,x,y,z,height, width):
return True # Or False
```

Thank you ! :)

*EDIT :*

```
def collision_filet(X,Y,Z):   

    for i in range(len(X)):
        if (abs(X[i]) + radius <= WIDTH_TABLE/2.):
                    if Y[i]>=1.37 - 0.015 and Y[i]<= 1.37 + 0.015:
                        if Z[i]>=0 and Z[i]<= 0.1525:
                            return True
    return False
```

**The curve I have is defined by consecutive points of the lists X Y and Z**.
The way I do it right now is by checking if each point is within a box that's a little bigger than the rectangle I want to check the of the curve collision with.
The problem of this technique is that it requires to have a curve with a lot of points which takes a lot of computing time and that I dont want.

*EDIT* 2 : I can give you more details about my problem to help you seeing it better. So I have the curve of a ping pong ball as it goes over the ball the ping pong table. The thing is that I need to create a function that checks whether the ball trajectory intersects with the net of the table (length : 1.83m, height : 0.15m, we can consider it's width to be null and the bottom line of the rectangle touches the table at z = 0).

[So this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktMzy.png)

So since my curve is defined by consecutive points of the lists, **I want to check for each consecutive points whether the line that separates them intersects with the rectangle of the net** and this is where I'm stuck at.

*EDIT3* : I managed to solve my problem by splitting it in two segment intersection problems

Comment: Just how do those lists define the curve? Is the curve linear between consecutive points? Are you looking for an intersection with the perimeter of the rectangle or with the 2D region within and on the rectangle? Also, explain further how the rectangle is defined by those parameters to your function--it is not clear to me. Finally, what have you tried, and just where are you stuck? You need to show some effort of your own in the form of attempted code or an algorithm.

Comment: The  curve is defined by consecutive points of the lists, and yes I'm looking for the intersection of the curve with the whole area of the rectangle. The rectangle actually simply is a rectangle with length 1.83 and height 0.15 and of the bottom line of the rectangle touches the table at z = 0

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications; I am removing my close vote, though it may be too late to get your question re-opened. I still am not clear about how the rectangle is defined from the parameters. If I answer, may I just assume the rectangle that you describe in your added details?

Comment: Yes sure you can